# Логин в блокирующем режиме в Netty

Tags: java, сокет, io, netty

Имеется сокет клиент, написанный на Netty. Перед тем как начать передавать данные, я должен проверить, залогинился пользователь или нет, и отправляю для этого данные пользователя на сервер. Остальные данные я должен отправить лишь в том случае, если получу положительный ответ с сервера. Т.е. пока не получу ответ от сервера, я не могу отправить другие данные. Как можно это реализовать в Netty?

Мой код следующий:

```
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();   
try {
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.group(workerGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .handler(new TRSClientInterfaceInitializer());

    Channel ch = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
    ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;

    for (Message message : list) {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush("loginpassword");
        }
        //if login is success, I must loop through all data in list and send other data to server
        lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(message.getDataString);
    }

    if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
        lastWriteFuture.sync();
    }
} catch ////
```

И мой handler:

```
//handler extended from SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String>
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String data) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.flush();
    if ("success".equals(data)) {
        isLoggedIn = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки:

1)

```
for (Message message : list) {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush("loginpassword");
        }
        //if login is success, I must loop through all data in list and send other data to server
        lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(message.getDataString);
    }
```

У вас авторизация выполнится столько раз, сколько у вас сообщений для отправки.

2) `lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(message.getDataString);`
вообще смысла не имеет, так как в данный момент вы всегда ещё не авторизованы

Вы в хендлер должны прокидывать ссылку, как пример, на класс, который инициализировал коннект (сам коннект засейвить в глобальную переменную надо, кстати). После получения ответа хендлер вызывает этот класс, а он уже череp сохранённый коннект отправит данныt, если авторизация удачна.

**Btw**, так же не помешало бы почитать про Future/Promise